# $e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B$ when $A$ and $B$ are commuting unbounded self-adjoint operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider $A$ and $B$ two unbounded self-adjoint operators on the complex separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Suppose that $AB=BA$ (maybe on a common domain $\mathcal{D}(AB-BA)$).

Is it true that $e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}$? Again, is it true that $e^Ae^B=e^Be^A$?

I think the answer to both these questions is negative, and that we need strong commutativity of $A$ and $B$. Am I right? Thank you!

Comment: You need conditions on the ranges and the domains of the operators.

Comment: What is meant by strong commutativity?

Comment: You can see in Reed and Simon, page 271. $A$ and $B$ strongly commute if and only if their projections commute.